# How can get all users by current user meta?

Tags: php, user-meta, array

I have a block system to make users block each other, My question is how to get all users by current user meta by the array?

When current user is blocked anther user it's saved as meta like this: `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"3";}` so user ID 1 block user ID 3.

So I need to make a specific page to get all users that the current user is blocked by checking current user meta `blocking_users`' to get the blocked users from it.

Any idea example how can make it?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function and its meta_key argument as displayed below.

```
$users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key'     => 'blocking_users',
));

var_dump( $users );
```

To retrieve it for current user and print it, please use below code.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$key = 'blocking_users';
$single = false;
$blocking_users = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: </p>'; 
print_r($blocking_users);
```

Comment: how can print it? and how can choose to get blocking_users for the current user only

Comment: @Yogu I have added code in the above answer to achieve this.

Comment: I already try this but it gives me: The blocking_users value for user id 1 is: Array.

Comment: I have modified code so please try again.

Comment: Really thank you for your help, it's now give me: Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) not the users name that in blocking_users meta.

can this code help: https://mattvarone.com/wordpress/list-users-with-wp_user_query/

Comment: Make sure blocking_users is the meta field of user profile and contains values. If possible share the screenshot of values entered.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/B6OD0Go.png

Comment: The shared screenshot is not useful at all so please share whole page screenshot.

Comment: it's a screenshot from usermeta table using Navicat, this is the meta for user id 1 (admin) and to know if anther user is blocked from user id 1 or not I using in_array and it's worked.